# Extremely slow Wordpress website with 6000 posts

Tags: performance, hosting, cache

I have a website with 6000 posts and it is extremely slow.

Sometimes I get this error in my browser:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

I have turned almost all plugins off and it is slow in frontend and in backend too, so I guess it is not because of  the template.

Could it be because of WP_navigation plugin?

I have est. 600 pages with ten posts or WP navigation plugin, could this be the problem?

Comment: On one site I've got more than that-- nearly 10,000 in one post type, another couple of thousand in another, and a bunch of pages-- and I don't have any issue. It might be that plugin but I don't use it. Do you have the same problem if you disable it?

Comment: Echoing s_ha_dum's comment, I manage sites with posts in the five figure range too and they're plenty fast.  What happens if you turn off that plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress can be a resource hog if you don't use caching. W3 Total Cache could help you a lot with MySQL, Object and Page Caching. You should also install PHP-APC and use it with the plugin. It can do wonders.

Answer (score 1):

I got like 8,000 posts so it's def. not the problems.

However, you may want to optimize your WordPress setup a bit.

- APC (opcode caching)
- w3tc (caching plugin)

For $5 plan hosting on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=e5601d1e9d5f) (ref link), I was able to host a WordPress site with 8,000 posts and ~ 180,000 page views per day; with the above simple setup.

Also, you may want to take a look at plugin/widget like Popular posts. it's a resource hog.

Answer (score 0):

Caching plugin definitely helps as Alex already mentioned. But you will still hit a resource limit when you get a lot of visitors. There is a point you can't do much more than upgrading your hosting plan for more resources.

Consider a hosting provider such as WPEngine which automatically optimize your WordPress with caching and allows you to easily upgrade the plan. I work with a client with millions of website hits and they pay hundreds of dollars on hosting plan to accomodate it.